# how to use .dll files in java code?

Tags: java, .net, dll, java-native-interface

I have a .dll file, which i have to use in java. This .dll file has a parameterised method, which should return type as string. 
When i am passing parameter to it, i get the message as `Native methods do not specify a body`

Here is the Code...

```
package com.letme.test;

public class Eagleye_parser {

    String n = "E48A7 F7759 65EA7";

    public Eagleye_parser() {}

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Eagleye_parser");
    }

    public native String eagleye_fmu(n);// here it is giving msg : Native methods do not specify a body 
}
```

Comment: Please tell me how can it be done

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add the reference in you project. and the namespace at the top.. then you can access the all dll methods.
If your are using Eclispe then right click on your project->Then click on Build path-> then click on Add libraries after that click on user library

Here you can import the dll

Comment: I tried the way you are telling. but i am unable to import the .dll, the error msg i m getting is : _"the seleted file is not a valid user library file"_

Comment: i think you are doing something wrong. did you create a package project in Eclispe.

Comment: Okey Can you give me the dll so i can try what is the problem exactly.. in adding refrence..?

Comment: Sure @rahul, but please give me your email id such that i can contact you meanwhile, i can give the dll also.

Comment: okey this is my emailid: rkumar670@gmail.com or you can check my stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 2):

Try having a look at JNA, it provides a nice wrapper layer around native code.

https://github.com/twall/jna

Answer (score 0):

`public native String eagleye_fmu(n);` The 'n' here is the problem as it would be a problem with any other java function declaration.

This should be something like `public native String eagleye_fmu(String);` then you call the native function like any other function `String result = eagleye_fmu(n);`

This is all assuming you have the dll implemented properly

Comment: this is what i am getting 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245767/unable-to-use-dll-file-in-the-java-code