# unable to use .dll file in the Java code

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use .dll files in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208914/how-to-use-dll-files-in-java-code)

The dll file, I am using, is giving error:

The error message is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: Eagleye_parser
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:767)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1005)
    at test.TestDllJava.<clinit>(TestDllJava.java:15)
Exception in thread "main"
```

This is the code:

```
public class TestDllJava {

    private static native String[] eagleye_fmu(String A);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] ag = null;
        String parameter =  null;
        parameter = "356188030442449 10250000 0001F464 0000EB34 0002CC7D 4xA0";
         ag = eagleye_fmu(parameter);
        System.out.println(ag);
    }

    static { 
        System.load("Eagleye_parser");
    } 
}
```

Please correct me, where I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you try specifying an absolute path? what does this have to do with .net?

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs of load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) specify:

> Loads a code file with the specified filename from the local file
>   system as a dynamic library. **The filename argument must be a complete
>   path name.**

A better approach without stating an absolute path to library is by using [loadLibrary()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) or maybe `load(`[`mapLibraryName(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#mapLibraryName%28java.lang.String%29)`)`.

In Eclipse, you can specify native library folder in your project via project Properties -> Java build Path -> tab Libraries -> expand your System Library, click Native Library Location. Eclipse will build `java.library.path` for you and `loadLibrary()` will then see it easily.

[image: Screenshot of Project Properties]

Comment: `loadLibrary()` is the way to go.

Comment: I have Tried loadLibrary() also, the problem remains the same
msg as follows:
_java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Eagleye_parser in java.library.path_

Comment: Then try to follow the instructions I gave you about adding the file to Libraries. You can edit `java.library.path` manually, but it is not considered good practice since IDE should do it for you.

Comment: as loadLibrary search for the Library, can you tell me how to specify that library in the project that to be added in the eclipse...

Comment: @Slanec as you told me to do... I did the same way But still it is showing the same error. 
_java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: Eagleye_parser_

Comment: With the library added to your project Libraries, use `loadLibrary()` method. This exception you see is thrown by `load()` which you don't want to use (as it is used when you can specify an absolute path to it).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.TestDllJava.eagleye_fmu(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 at test.TestDllJava.eagleye_fmu(Native Method)
 at test.TestDllJava.main(TestDllJava.java:11)

This the Error, now show when i changed it to _loadLibrary()_ method. Could you suggest me what can i do.

Comment: What is the message of the Error? In the Java 7 code, I can't see any place where `UnsatisfiedLinkError` could pop out without a message.

Comment: @Slanec are you using JAVA 7 or what? I am using java 6.
Could you please connect me @ **aqravi01@gmail.com**, such that i can show you the code.